# What is the meaning of apt-get install --reinstall?

Tags: command-line, apt

When running

```
apt-get install --reinstall XXX
```

What is really happening? Does this purge the old binaries then replace again? or just replace the new binary without purging the old one?

In other words `--reinstall=remove+install`  or `--reinstall=install/update` and if it's remove then install would this be `purge` or `remove` which means would that remove configurations beside the binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which means would that remove configurations beside the binaries?

No. It will remove the package and NOT the dependencies and reinstall only the package. Config files are left as they are.

If you also want to re-install config files you can remove them yourself and use

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall {package}
```

to reinstall those along with the package.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install --reinstall xxx`completely removes the package (but not the config files or the packages that depend on xxx) and reinstalls the newest version of the package. So I guess it is running `remove` and not `purge`.

Reference:

https://superuser.com/questions/102449/how-to-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get

Comment: I need to check out the sources to verify, but this is wrong, reinstall doesn't remove the files already placed on the system.

Comment: better check out the sources..right? :P